# Trouble installing Devise gem

Tags: ruby, devise, rubygems

I just attempted installing devise and had some trouble. From previous experience I know that when I install it I am required to do some manual steps. Well this time there where no manual steps but I still did them because I know they had to be done. So everything is working fine but then I run `rails g devise: views` this returns

```
/Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:469:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. 
Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)

config.secret_key = '1ef096dceb32ce5af3b11a7ef99c00ab59b7ad90ed5dbacabe5e8cb8613e437799333b96e2045997d701a1ed1b1fde537b98f6ef1c64d247516b85c9410ad147'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:203:in `devise_for'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/Desktop/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/Desktop/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/Desktop/pinteresting/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
  from /Users/henrywyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: you literally just need to add `config.secret_key = '1ef096dceb32ce5af3b11a7ef99c00ab59b7ad90ed5dbacabe5e8cb8613e437799333b96e2045997d701a1ed1b1fde537b98f6ef1c64d247516b85c9410ad147'` to your devise file, that's it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
config.secret_key = '1ef096dceb32ce5af3b11a7ef99c00ab59b7ad90ed5dbacabe5e8cb8613e437799333b96e204599‌​7d701a1ed1b1fde537b98f6ef1c64d247516b85c9410ad147'
```

to your devise file (config/initializers/devise_initializer.rb).

Comment: The problem is I dont have a (config/initializers/devise_initializer.rb).

Comment: You probably didn't run ```rails generate devise:install``` first, then. Do that, and you'll have devise installed.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on production dont put this in any config file rather put it as environment variable 
rails 4 have one secret.yml file in which there is a line

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

you just need to set ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]

I am not sure but secret key is any string

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem 
but resolved it after restarting my rails server